# Campo dentro de uma variável dinamicamente usando array

Tags: c#

Aqui tenho código:

```
byte[] Imagem1 = null;
byte[] Imagem2 = null;
byte[] Imagem3 = null;
byte[] Imagem4 = null;
byte[] Imagem5 = null;
byte[] Imagem6 = null;
```

Como posso declarar os variáveis bytes[] dentro de um array ?

Já tentei esse:

```
byte[] imagem = new byte[6];
```

Problema:

```
foreach (string item in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item] as HttpPostedFileBase;
    imagem[0] = ConvertToBytes(file);
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'byte'
```

Outro exemplo:

```
int[] inteiros = new int[5];

inteiros[0] = 154;
inteiros[1] = 02555;
```

Sei que isso funciona pelo int ou string, só não consigo pelo byte[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está aqui: `imagem[0] = ConvertToBytes(file);`

```
byte[] imagem = new byte[6];

foreach (string item in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[item] as HttpPostedFileBase;
    imagem[0] = ConvertToBytes(file);
}
```

O correto seria

```
byte[] imagem = new byte[6];
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in Request.Files)
{
    imagem = ConvertToBytes(item);
}
```

Talvez o que você precisa é disso:

```
List<byte[]> imagens=new List<byte[]>();

for ( int i=0;i<Request.Files.Count();i++)
{
   imagens.Add( ConvertToBytes(Request.Files[i]));
}
```

Mas do jeito que você está fazendo, o correto seria:

```
byte[] Imagem1 = null;
byte[] Imagem2 = null;
byte[] Imagem3 = null;
byte[] Imagem4 = null;
byte[] Imagem5 = null;
byte[] Imagem6 = null;

foreach (HttpPostedFileBase item in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = item;
    if(Imagem1 == null)
       Imagem1 = ConvertToBytes(file);
    if(Imagem2 == null)
       Imagem2 = ConvertToBytes(file);
    if(Imagem3 == null)
       Imagem3 = ConvertToBytes(file);
    if(Imagem4 == null)
       Imagem4 = ConvertToBytes(file);
    if(Imagem5 == null)
       Imagem5 = ConvertToBytes(file);
    if(Imagem6 == null)
       Imagem6 = ConvertToBytes(file);
}
```

Comment: Tiago S, funcionou aqui, obrigado.